# failed to install face_recognition, pillow, dilib

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, face-recognition

I am facing this(failed to install face_recognition, pillow, dilib) problems more than 3 hours but it can not install. please solve anyone . here is error massage

```
Collecting face-recognition==1.3.0
  Using cached face_recognition-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\ajay kumar\downloads\attendance\venv\lib\site-packages (from face-recognition==1.3.0) (1.23.5)
Requirement already satisfied: face-recognition-models>=0.3.0 in c:\users\ajay kumar\downloads\attendance\venv\lib\site-packages (from face-recognition==1.3.0) (0.3.0)
Collecting dlib>=19.7
  Using cached dlib-19.24.0.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Requirement already satisfied: Click>=6.0 in c:\users\ajay kumar\downloads\attendance\venv\lib\site-packages (from face-recognition==1.3.0) (7.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in c:\users\ajay kumar\downloads\attendance\venv\lib\site-packages (from face-recognition==1.3.0) (9.3.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
  Building wheel for dlib (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for dlib (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Running setup.py clean for dlib
Failed to build dlib
Installing collected packages: dlib, face-recognition
    Running setup.py install for dlib: started
    Running setup.py install for dlib: finished with status 'error'

  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\Ajay Kumar\Downloads\ATTENDANCE\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Ajay Kumar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-milseje2\\dlib_309f909f3c144f8cb6e2594feb25911f\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Ajay Kumar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-milseje2\\dlib_309f909f3c144f8cb6e2594feb25911f\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Ajay Kumar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-_d9j585t'
       cwd: C:\Users\Ajay Kumar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-milseje2\dlib_309f909f3c144f8cb6e2594feb25911f\
  Complete output (8 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  package init file 'tools\python\dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
  running build_ext
  
  ERROR: CMake must be installed to build dlib
  
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\Ajay Kumar\Downloads\ATTENDANCE\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Ajay Kumar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-milseje2\\dlib_309f909f3c144f8cb6e2594feb25911f\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Ajay Kumar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-milseje2\\dlib_309f909f3c144f8cb6e2594feb25911f\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Ajay Kumar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-cv4pvl8s\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Ajay Kumar\Downloads\ATTENDANCE\venv\include\site\python3.11\dlib'
         cwd: C:\Users\Ajay Kumar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-milseje2\dlib_309f909f3c144f8cb6e2594feb25911f\
    Complete output (10 lines):
    running install
    C:\Users\Ajay Kumar\Downloads\ATTENDANCE\venv\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
      warnings.warn(
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'tools\python\dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    running build_ext
    
    ERROR: CMake must be installed to build dlib
    
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\Ajay Kumar\Downloads\ATTENDANCE\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Ajay Kumar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-milseje2\\dlib_309f909f3c144f8cb6e2594feb25911f\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Ajay Kumar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-milseje2\\dlib_309f909f3c144f8cb6e2594feb25911f\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Ajay Kumar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-cv4pvl8s\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Ajay Kumar\Downloads\ATTENDANCE\venv\include\site\python3.11\dlib' Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.3.1; however, version 22.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\Ajay Kumar\Downloads\ATTENDANCE\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

installing face_recognition, pillow, dilib library in python

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install **CMake** before build **dlib**

```
ERROR: CMake must be installed to build dlib
```

edit: Official cmake site https://cmake.org/download/

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: cmake in c:\users\kumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (3.25.0)

Comment: I have already installed cmake but same problem

Comment: https://cmake.org/download/ this cmake not python package